# Python capturing stdout/stderr and logging to file while seeing output

Tags: python, linux, logging

So I have a python script that's trying to automate an entire build procedure. As such, it is calling not only python files, but shell scripts, maven, etc. So what I want is a method/procedure/library to capture the outputs to stdout and stderr to a logfile while still printing it to the console even if the thing printing to the console is not a python script.

We're working on a linux machine so when doing this manually, we'd do a `script`, then all the commands, then an `exit`. But when trying to wrap this in a python script, it seems that script takes command of the shell and doesn't allow me to run the rest of my commands until I `exit` first.

For proof of concept, here's a bash script that prints a number every half second up to 10.

`print_nums.bash`

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
do
    echo "$i"
    sleep 0.5
done
```

And here is what I've kind of want to do.

`test_script.py`

```
import os

def main():
    cmd1 = "script /some/arbitrary/path/logfile.txt"
    cmd2 = "/path/to/print_nums.bash"
    cmd3 = "exit"

    os.system(cmd1)

    os.system(cmd2)

    os.system(cmd3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've also looked into the logging module, but it seems that only easily captures python prints to a log. I may be mistaken, and if there's an inutuitive way I'd definitely be willing to change methodologies. But essentially, I want to be able, in python, to effectively say from here I want to log the console output, and here I want to end the logging it programmatically.

You can imagine that a build command and initial testing can take a long amount of time like 15 - 20 minutes, which is a long time to have a console waiting without any output if you just did a

`some_command.bash > logfile.txt`.

Comment: Take a look at the subprocess module and you can use the stdout and stderr kwargs to pipe the output to a log file. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout

Comment: Will just using the `-c` option of `script` work? Like `cmd1 = "script -c /path/to/print_nums.bash /some/arbitrary/path/logfile.txt"`. Then you only need the first `os.system(cmd1)`.

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry As far as I know how, if I do something like Popen([cmd], stdout='logfile.txt', stderr='logfile.txt'), that doesn't print to the console. If I use a PIPE, then I'll have to wait until it completes to read the pipe and print to my logfile, unless there's a good way to dynamically print to the console while it's being saved to the logfile, something similiar to `tail -f logfile.txt` ?.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I get a `print_nums.bash: Command not found.` even though it seems to be pointing to the right place. But this seems promising.

Comment: Make sure the path is correct to `print_nums.bash` and that the permissions are correct (`chmod 755 /path/to/print_nums.bash`).

Comment: @JohnAnderson yeah, both were done to being with. Maybe it's an issue between bash and sh? I don't really know how script works, but if exit closes it, maybe it assumes a different shell?

Comment: @JohnAnderson actually. for some reason, it works on another linux machine. So Thank you very much!

Comment: [How does the tee command work](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+does+the+tee+command+work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way for me was the answer from jww. Use `tee` in the python script in conjunction with `os.system` and `tee -a` if you need to append the output of another script to the same logfile.

`test_script.py`

```
import os


def main():
    cmd1 = "path/to/aribitrary_script | tee /path/to/logfile"
    cmd2 = "path/to/another_script | tee -a /path/to/logfile"

    os.system(cmd1)
    os.system(cmd2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: if your script is another python script, then tee might suppress the output to stdout. If this is the case, call your python script explicitly with 

`cmd = 'python -u python_script | tee /path/to/logfile'`